# .eslintignore file not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, eslint

I'm using a Vue template project that uses ESLint.  I'd like to turn it off, so I followed these instructions and made a file with

```
**/*.js
```

called `.eslintignore` inside of my project root.  However, I'm still getting the same eslint error messages.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to disable eslint from linting your code?

Comment: @samayo  I don't know anything about eslint, I just want the error messages to go away

Comment: I [understand you very well](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73#issuecomment-324641423)

Comment: did you get this working? I am still not able to do it.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the `vscode-eslint` plugin, the `.eslintignore` file may need to be placed at the root of the workspace folder, in order to be recognized by the vscode plugin.

Comment: Or you can also add this config in `.vscode/settings.json`:
`{"eslint.workingDirectories": ["./path/to/nested/front/project"]}`
In this case, your `.eslintignore` file should be located in the nested path location (you have a front project in a nested folder inside the main project at root).

Answer (score 9):

For my configuration - I needed to add the "ignorePatterns" property in .eslintrc:

`"ignorePatterns": "**/*.d.ts"`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `**/*` instead of `**/*.js` as the first will ignore both `.js` and `.vue` files.

Alternatively you can comment this whole block in your `build/webpack.base.conf.js`

```
{
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: "pre",
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
  options: {
      formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but after changing it, I'm still getting the same error messages.

Comment: Try to restart the server. It should work, specially the second option as I have eslint turned off as well

Comment: Somehow this doesn't seem to be working.  I stop the dev server and run `npm run dev` again, but get the same messages.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong but you should be able to find your answer here https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73#issuecomment-324641423

Comment: Thanks for trying :)

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't work. But if you're really struggling `ESLint` has a fix command: `eslint --fix` which fixes all the 'issues' it throws up. Why ESLint has been added to the dev config in the first place is another question.

Answer (score 2):

I love ESLint but sometimes you want it to completely ignore a whole file. Add this to the top of your file:

`/* eslint-disable */`

It needs to be in `/* this kind */` of comment, not `//` this kind.

And ESLint won't complain about your file any more!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this if I can't find a project-wide solution

Comment: Sure, why not. I used it once in a small project.

Answer (score -1):

## Valid

/root/src/*.js

## Invalid

\root\src*.js